# High charts, providing data for xAxis instead of Series

Tags: highcharts

As you can see in example:

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/bar-stacked/

```
plotOptions: {
            series: {
                stacking: 'normal'
            }
        },
```

the data is provided in series for John, Jane and Joe in series.
Instead, what I would like to do, is just provide the data for Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas' such as:

Apples: 1,2,3,4,5 (will all display on the first bar) 
Oranges: 10,20,30,40,50 (will all display on the second bar)
etc...

So I can provide the data PER BAR instead of across...

is it possible?

Thanks for reading,

Sean.

Comment: Defaulty it is not build-in, but you can use your own data and then prepare parser which will convert it to correct highcharts form.

Comment: What is the use case for the chart you are plotting? i need to understand your requirement..can you elaborate? what will 1,2,3,4,5 in apples signify?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is this: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/4vG42/)**;

To obtain such an output chart instead of a stacked chart, just comment out the code section show belwo like:

```
plotOptions: {
                /*series: {
                    stacking: 'normal'
                }*/
            },
```

**Commenting out the above section of code will convert a stacked bar chart into a normal bar chart with individual bars for the categories.**

Comment: thx for the reply, but with the demo you provided, the bars are not stacked... :(

Comment: then, are you looking for something like : http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/C7heA/ ? Let me know your views so that I can update my answer.